# Why is my div being messed up with a table on a tablet?

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

Look at the following code to see my problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>

<body>


<div style='width:100%; background:#CCCCCC; padding:0px; margin:0px; margin-bottom:20px; border:1px solid #CCC;'>

   <div style='float:left'>
      <a href='#' title='CSS TEST'><span style='font-size:30px;'>TEST for CSS DIV</span></a>
   </div>

   <div style='float:right'>
      Stuff on the right
   </div>

   <div style='clear:both;'></div>

</div>

<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' align='center' width='1200' border='1'>

   <tr>

   <td> COL1 </td>
   <td> COL3 </td>

   </tr>

</table>

</body>

</html>
```

The above cuts my div down from 100% if viewed on a tablet. But works fine on the pc.

If I remove the table, the div spans 100%

Any help would be appreciated.

You can see this code live at http://zeissimages.com/test.html

Again it works fine on a tablet ONLY if you remove the table definition.

Comment: Must be some CSS stuff going on that we can't see here.  Can you put your code outside of a php file and reproduce the issue?

Comment: @clrockwell I edited the post and added actual code and a link to see it in action

Answer (score 0):

don't you mean:

```
<div style="width:100%">
bla bla bla
</div>

<table style="width:800px;">
..
..
</table>
```

Can't suggest much without the real code...

Comment: I added the real code to original post.  If you get rid of the table code, the div spans the entire width of the window in a tablet. If you insertthe table code the div is narrowed and looks smaller.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I can not reproduce on any browser (including switching user agents to mimic a tablet) but I see the error on 2 HP touchpads (one with stock WebOS, the other with Android ICS).  If I put the code in jsfiddle and view it on a tablet (in embedded mode) the issue doesn't exist.

First, you should move your `<div style="clear:both"></div>` so that it is between your first main div and the table, like:

```
<div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<table></table>
```

Does that resolve it?

Just in case, I'll mention that you shouldn't include all those inline styles unless it's the only option.  Additionally, you can exclude the clearing div altogether if you clear the table.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it mad it worse :( Sorry :) This is really puzzling since it the styling is so basic. I just can't grasp what is goig on here with the table.